# Error: A trigger returned a resultset and the server option 'disallow results from triggers' is true

Tags: entity-framework

I am in a simple environment - .NET, Web Forms, Entity Framework Code First, SQL Server 2014. When I publish to the server, my application's first touch of the database, when I would expect EF to create tables, produces the error:

```
A trigger returned a resultset and the server option 'disallow results from triggers' is true
```

In case this has something to do with my database initializer, the code is:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Do you have any migrations or special code in your model creation?

Comment: No migrations. No stored procedures. No triggers (that I know of). Just a simple model.